# Search for a word on webpage

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

i found some posts aobut this subject, tried them, but can't get them to work.

- I need to create a script that takes 2 command-line arguments: inputfile and outputfile.
- The inputfile is in the filesystem, with content: url, word(s) per line.
- I then want to open url and search for word(s) it has after comma.
- After that i want to save the result to a [] and append 'YES' or 'NO' if the word(s) were found.
- That [] should be written and saved to a outputfile.

My code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Tested Python version: 2.7.12
#
# Run "./script.py [inputfile.txt] [outputfile.txt]"
#
# Exit codes:
# 1 - Python version not tested
# 2 - Wrong number command-line arguments
# 3 - Input file, with this name, does not exist
# 4 - Output file, with this name, already exists
# 5 - Problem with input file
# 6 - Problem with output file

import os, sys
import urllib2, re

# Check python version
req_version = (2, 7)

if not sys.version_info[:2] == req_version:
     print '...'
     print 'Not tested Python version (2.7).'
     print 'Your Python version: ', sys.version_info[:2]
     print '...'
     sys.exit(1)

# Check command-line arguments
if len(sys.argv) < 3:
     print '...'
     print 'Missing command-line argument(s).'
     print 'Argument list:', str(sys.argv)
     print '...'
     sys.exit(2)

# Check if files exist
if not os.path.exists(sys.argv[1]):
     print '...'
     print 'Input file %s was not found.' % sys.argv[1]
     print '...'
     sys.exit(3)

if os.path.exists(sys.argv[2]):
     print '---'
     print 'Output file %s already exists.' % sys.argv[2]
     print '---'
     sys.exit(4)

# Read input file line by line, make a list of URL-s and write the
# results to output file
inputfile = sys.argv[1]
outputfile = sys.argv[2]

print '---'
print 'Reading input file %s ..'  % inputfile
print '---'

results = []

try:
     with open(inputfile, 'r') as in_f:

         for line in in_f:

             url = line.strip().split(',')[0]
             word = line.strip().split(',')[1]
             site = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

             print 'Found "%s" on "%s" ->' % (word, url)

             # matches = re.search(word)
             # if re.search(word, url):
             # if len(matches) == 0:
             if site.find(word) != -1:
                 print 'YES'
                 results.append('.'.join(url, word + ' YES')))
             else:
                 print 'NO'
                 results.append('.'.join(url, word + ' NO')))
except:
     print 'Error reading the file'
     sys.exit(5)

#if not inputfile.closed:
#     inputfile.close()
print '>>>' + inputfile + ' closed: ' + inputfile.closed

print '...'
print 'Writing results to output file %s ..' % outputfile
print '...'

try:
     with open(outputfile, 'w'):
         for item in results:
             outputfile.write((results) + '\n')
             print '>>>' + outputfile.read()
except:
     print 'Error writing to file'
     sys.exit(6)

#if not outputfile.closed:
#     outputfile.close()
print '>>>' + outputfile + ' closed: ' + outputfile.closed

print ''
print '>>> End of script <<<'
print ''
```

When i run ./script.py inputfile_name.txt outputfile_name.txt, i get except in terminal from reading inputfile:

```
...
Reading input file inputfile_name txt ..
...
Error reading the file
```

Could somebody please point out the possible fault in my code. Can't figure it out.

**EDIT:** moved the variables (url, word, site) under 'for' block and added print after. The script does print first line of url, word but does not print the "Found ...." % word, url after that. If i remove the print url, word then the script gives except error right away.
**EDIT2:** made changes as suggested by user Oluwafemi Sule. The script works until the inputfile has multiple words after url (sentence), then it gives except.

Comment: You have too much code under `try`, so it's masking whatever the error is and making it hard to debug. Suggest you move non essential code outside it

Comment: Specifically, you're saying `url = line.strip().split(',')[0]` before `line` is defined.

Comment: I moved the variable declaration under 'for' block but script still does not go further. it does open the file for reading, prints the first line from 'for' block and that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **error** in your code is from appending to `results` list with an incorrect number of arguments.

```
results.append(url, word + ' YES')
```

can be written as appending a joined string of url, word and verdict delimited by `,`:

```
results.append(','.join((url, word, 'YES')))
```

**BONUS:**

### Things that can change in your code

The following code block:

```
url = line.strip().split(',')[0]
word = line.strip().split(',')[1]
```

can be rewritten as:

```
url, word = line.strip().split(',')
```

to **save from splitting line twice**

The following blocks can be removed as *context managers* handle file closing implicitly.

```
if not inputfile.closed:
     inputfile.close()
print '>>>' + inputfile + ' closed: ' + inputfile.closed
```

And

```
if not outputfile.closed:
     outputfile.close()
print '>>>' + outputfile + ' closed: ' + outputfile.closed
```

Lastly, **out_f isn't being written to**. That's a potential `AttributeError` calling write on a `string`.

Comment: I corrected the append and changed the url, word declaration. Also removed the file closing lines. I still get the same error. If i add "print url, word" then only one line is printed to the console (in the inputfile i have multiple lines: "url,some strings to search" and after that the except. It's like it has problem with reading line by line as it does not print the print the "'Found "%s" on "%s" ->' % word, url" line.

Comment: Update the print statement format args to a tuple. `print 'Found "%s" on "%s" ->' % (word, url)`

Comment: Thanks! It now iterates 4 rows and then gives except. what happens on row 5 in inputfile is that it has a long phrase: "url,many words after this url". theese words need to be searched as a sentence.

Comment: Ok. so the real problem that is happening after 4th line in inputfile is that the script gets to invalid url. so i need to add url validation.

Comment: Ah, I see. You may want to match specific exception instances in your except statement instead of generalizing the handling of exceptions. See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Comment: but that would still stop the script from reading the next line? i would need to add condition before searching the words? nested if with smk of response == True condition?

Comment: I'm recommending to handle the specific exception raised which is an IOError. You can handle it by writing `except IOError as exc:`. If your decided strategy is to skip the failing line, you can `pass` the exception. Otherwise, validating the url or auto-correcting it can be a better strategy.